# ¿Cómo definir un radio botón por default dentro de una etiqueta form? ANGULAR/TYPESCRIPT

Tags: angular, typescript

Lo que intento hacer es que un radio botón quede seleccionado por default dentro de una etiqueta form. Ya lo intenté con "Checked" pero no funciona
¿Alguna idea?

```
div *ngFor="let file of files">
<div *ngIf="file.downloadURL | async as downloadURL">
    <form  [formGroup]="urlForm" (ngSubmit)="enviar()">
    <input type="radio" [value]="downloadURL" formControlName='url'name="url" checked=""  >
</form>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">enviar</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu FormGroup, donde especificas tu control, le añades el valor, que será el estado inicial de tu input.

Para tu caso en este campo seria asi.

```
this.urlForm = new FormGroup({
      url: new FormControl(this.downloadURL)
    });
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional para que lo valides.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dew-mls3g?file=/src/app/app.component.ts